# Opening MS Access 2003 .mdb in VB6 code

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I'm trying to open an .mdb Access file in MS Access 2003 using VB6 code in order to open a report within that access.

Edit: I've tried a few things and now found out that we use ULS (User Level Security) to access our databases with Access in the company. The problem is that OpenCurrentDatabase does not seem to support this. I found a post telling me to make a workspace first and then open the database from within that workspace, but that wont work. the new code ive tried is below:
My Code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
     us = "xxxx"
     pw = "xxxx"
     Set acc = New Access.Application
     Set ws = acc.DBEngine.CreateWorkspace("test1", us, pw)
End Sub
```

Now I need to somehow open that access database from within that workspace so the ULS will work with it. Any ideas?
Relevant System Information:

- MS Access Version: 2003
- OS: Windows 7 64 bit SP6
- VB IDE : Ms Visual Basic 6.0
- Library: Microsoft Access 10.0 Object Library.

The code above causes MS Access to launch but then deadlocks and doesn't do anything.

Comment: Wow `VB6`. You just reminded me of *Good Old Days* :) Loved that language

Comment: Is the 'True' the parameter for "exlusive"? Maybe not exklusive is a way

Comment: already tried, no dice.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax for opening report:

```
acc.Application.DoCmd.OpenReport "Bericht1", acViewNormal
```

...for closing report:

```
acc.Application.DoCmd.Close acReport, "Bericht1"
```

Comment: do I have to do that similarly for the opening statement?

Comment: No need. The earlier statements look OK

Comment: Tried that, still deadlocks on open. It does nothing for 5s then says something like "Cant continue operation because the other program was busy" and thats that

Comment: @E Mett Alright, got it to print the report. Now, how do I close the object after im done with it?